# Creating children actors in Akka Typed persistent actors

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence, akka-typed

Let’s assume an application implemented using Akka Typed has a persistent actor. This persistent actor as part of its operations creates transient (or non-persistent) children actors, each child has a unique ID and these IDs are part of the persisted state. The persistent actor also needs some way of communicating with its children, but we don’t want to persist children’s `ActorRef`s as they aren’t really part of the state. On recovery the persistent actor should recreate its children based on the recovered state. It doesn’t sound like a very unusual use case, I’m trying to figure out what’s the cleanest way of implementing it. I could create the children actors inside the `andThen` `Effect` in my command handler which is meant for side effects, but then there’s no way to save the child’s `ActorRef` from there. That seems to be a more general characteristic of the typed Persistence API - it’s very hard to have non-persistent state in persistent actors (which could be used for storing the transient children `ActorRef`s in this case). One solution I came up with is having a sort of “proxy” actor for creating children, keeping a map of IDs and `ActorRef`s, and forwarding messages based on IDs. The persistent actor holds a reference to that proxy actor and contacts it every time it needs to create a new child or send something to one of the existing children. I have mixed feelings about it though and would appreciate if somebody can point me to a better solution.

Comment: How are you recovering the persistent actor? Are you using snapshots or just journaled events?

Comment: No strict requirements on this, but ideally both.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using snapshots then the persistence mechanism does not store the `State` object, it stores the sequence of `Event`s that led to that `State` object. On recovery it simply re-plays those `Event`s in the order in which they happened and your `eventHandler` will return a modified `State` object that reflects the effect of each event.

This means that the `State` object can contain values that are not themselves persisted but are just set by the processing of certain `Event`s. They are, in effect, cached values derived from the persistent values in the `State`.

In your case the operation that causes the creation of a transient actor will be captured as an `Event` on the actor. So you can create the transient actor in the `eventHandler` and put the `ActorRef` in the new `State` object. When the actor is recovered it will replay that event and your actor will re-create the transient actor.

If you are using snapshots then I don't think there is a requirement that the snapshot object is the same type as your `State` object, so you can snapshot the state without the `ActorRef`s and re-create them when you get the `SnapshotOffer` message.

Comment: These are very good points, thanks for the suggestions. I've actually thought of creating the children actors in the event handler, but the thing is that the children themselves create side effects in the wider system, apart from having a  short and finite lifespan (they get created, they supervise a background task, and terminate once they are done). That's why I'd prefer to avoid creating children while replaying events, and delay that part until recovery is complete.

Comment: It would be great if typed persistent actors could have two types of state: persistent (only modified by eventHandler) and non-persistent (modifiable anywhere in the actor, be it eventHandler, commandHandler or post-recovery callback).

Comment: @s4nk I think the argument is that having `non-persistent state` breaks the purity of the model because it means that you can't fully restore the state from the persisted data and therefore you can't fully restore the actor.

Answer (score 1):

It's a design goal of typed persistence that the `State` be fully recoverable from the events (or from a snapshot and the events since that snapshot).

In general, the only way to have state that's non-persistent is to wrap the `EventSourcedBehavior` in a `Behaviors.setup` block which sets up the state.  One option for this is some sort of mutable state (e.g. a `var` or (likely exclusive or) mutable collection) in `setup`, which the command/event/recovery handlers manipulate.

A much more immutable alternative is to define an immutable fixture in `setup`, which includes a child actor which was spawned in `setup` to manage non-persistent state.  You can also put things like the entity ID or other things that are immutable for at least this incarnation of the entity into the fixture.